# how to create a utility to convert excel file into .XSD?

Tags: c#, excel, xsd

Can anyone help me to convert a specific excel file into a .xsd file? I Want a simple console application in C# to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

> I Want a simple console application in C# to do so?

Answer: Yes, probably You want.

This takes 3 easy steps:

- Loading the data in
- Generating xml data and scheme
- Validation

You can find a simple tutorial [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10581/Convert-Excel-to-XML-file-XML-Schema-and-validate).